# Evaluation of symbolic expressions in Octave

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

Let us suppose that we run the following set of commands in Octave:

```
pkg load symbolic %loads the symbolic math package 
syms x y %declare x and y symbols 
f = x^2 - 2*x + 3; 
V = [-5:0.25:5]'; 
V_x = subs(f, x, V)
```

At this point `V_x` is a symbolic expression in Octave. Now, if this were to be MATLAB, one would run `eval(V_x)` and everything would be converted to numbers. However, `eval` does not seem to run in Octave as in MATLAB.

What should be done to convert the symbolic array into numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`double`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/double.html) has been overloaded for symbolic variables so you can use `double` to explicitly convert the symbolic result to it's numeric representation

```
V_x_num = double(V_x);
```

This works in MATLAB as well as Octave.

Answer (score 0):

and how about getting variable precision (number of digits) in the evaluated symbolic output, ie, staying in the vpa symbolic space but solving all the sym internal functions to digits

eval still outputs in the default octave output_precision and format long limitations, so that is of no use.

this is one way (sym variable y holds the value):

```
sympref digits 1000
syms x
eqn = x==y
vpasolve(eqn)
```

Comment: Does `vpa(y)` not work?

Comment: seems to work, but somehow it did not work in some cases, i dont know, it left it in the function form in some cases or in my previous case (like a.bbbbbb * 0.5*sin(pi), but dont know.